# delete temporary file in java

Tags: java, file-io

I'm creating a temporary file in Java but I'm unable to delete it. This is the code I have written:

```
temp = File.createTempFile("temp", ".txt");
temp.deleteOnExit();
fileoutput = new FileWriter(temp);
buffout = new BufferedWriter(fileoutput);
```

Answer (score 27):

Add the following code (after you have done your operations with the file):

```
buffout.close();
fileoutput.close();
temp.delete();
```

As long as some stream on the file is open, it is locked (at least on the windows-implementation of the JVM). So it cannot be deleted.

It is good practice always to check if all opened streams get closed again after usage, because this is a bad memory-leak-situation. Your application can even eat up all available file-handles, that can lead to an unusable system.

Comment: Was about to write the same thing. As a rule, deleteOnExit() is rather unreliable. I would do the above, but also check the return value from temp.delete() to make sure that all locks are removed.

Comment: As Mike said, I would not rely on deleteOnExit(). Additionally the temporary file is kept until the end of the program-execution, even if no longer needed. On a server-application that can be a long time. So explicitly deleting the file is preferable.

Comment: Can you delete the file from Windows Explorer (assuming you're using Windows)?

Comment: By attempting and failing to explicitly delete the tmp files I created, I identified a resource leak in my code (a PrintStream I didn't close).

Answer (score 3):

There's a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4171239) saying that if the file is open by filewriter or anything, it won't be deleted. On windows. Check if you close your file writers.

Another workaround would be installing a [ShutdownHook](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4171239) which would manually delete the file.

Comment: deleteOnExit adds a shutdown hook

Answer (score 0):

You have to shut down a VM *cleanly* in order for the `deleteOnExit` to work properly (I suspect). On `UNIX` a `kill` would be a clean shutdown (i.e. the `ShutdownHooks` would be processed) whereas a `kill -9` would be more like a *force quit*.

`deleteOnExit` definitely works for me!

Comment: deleteOnExit keeps the file until the program ends. If the program only executes one action and stops afterwards that may be OK, but on a server-application the tempfiles are kept this way for a long time, accumulate and possibly eating up your inodes and your disk-space.

Comment: In the question, the use of deleteOnExit is not inappropriate - we've no idea what the specific usage pattern is. I would say that deleteOnExit is generally undesirable for a number of reasons (one being that it isn't reversible)

Answer (score 0):

Code to close the inpustream and outputstream:

```
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream();

     ArrayList list_in = new ArrayList<FileInputStream>();

     list_in.add(in);

     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream();

     ArrayList list_out = new ArrayList<OutputputStream>();

     list_in.add(out);

     public do_before_exit()
     {

      for(int i=0;i<list_in.size();i++)
      {
      FileInputStream in=(FileInputStream)list_in.get(i)
       FileInputStream out=(FileInputStream)list_out.get(i)

      in.close()
    out.close();
   }

}
```